# Express Node.js Cors preflight issue 400 net::ERR_FAILED

Tags: express, http-status-code-406

I have been banging my head against the wall for hours now... tried every type of combination to get this working.

I have my own API endpoint here: https://app.automate.mn/api/tools/email/add

Which I am trying to post data to from 3rd party websites.

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
    
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());

...
    
const {addContact} = require('./routes/api/tools/email');
app.post('/api/tools/email/add', addContact);
```

**addContact.js**

```
addContact: async function (req, res) {

    res.status(200).send('OK - TEST');
    return;
}
```

I have setup a test website here with the form: https://demoautomatemn.wpcomstaging.com/

When you submit the form, it's posting the data to the endpoint:

**loadForm.js**

```
automate_post_data('https://app.automate.mn/api/tools/email/add', data)
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data); // JSON data parsed by `data.json()` call
            });

async function automate_post_data(url = '', data = {}) {
const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
    },
    //referrerPolicy: 'origin', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
});

if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status} - ${response.statusText}`);
}
return response.json();
}
```

The post is failing:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://app.automate.mn/api/tools/email/add' from origin 'https://demoautomatemn.wpcomstaging.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
loadForm.js:109 POST https://app.automate.mn/api/tools/email/add net::ERR_FAILED
```

[image]

[image]

I was expecting to see the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in the response headers for the OPTION call but nothing ([Preflight response is not successful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40359565/preflight-response-is-not-successful)). I have tried everything to get it working.

Any suggestions would be so welcome right now.

Answer (score 0):

OK, Progress but no cigar!

I setup the following:

**Setting at apache level:**

https://docs.bitnami.com/bch/infrastructure/nodejs/administration/enable-cors-nodejs/

You might also find this helpful: https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

**Adding origin to the request**

```
 headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Origin': window.location.href
    },
referrerPolicy: 'origin',
```

This then resulted in the error message changing:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://app.automate.mn/api/tools/email/add' from origin 'https://demoautomatemn.wpcomstaging.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

**Update 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',**

As per this post: [Why doesn't adding CORS headers to an OPTIONS route allow browsers to access my API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/why-doesnt-adding-cors-headers-to-an-options-route-allow-browsers-to-access-my)

I updated the request to x-www-form-urlencoded

```
const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: method,
        mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Origin': window.location.href
        },
        referrerPolicy: 'origin', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
        body: data // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
    });
```

It feels like progress however I am still getting 406 error:

```
POST https://app.automate.mn/api/tools/email/add 406

Response {type: "cors", url: "https://app.automate.mn/api/tools/email/add", redirected: false, status: 406, ok: false, …}
```

Comment: Added in the following header and it seems to be working

'Accept': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',