# Failed to fetch: Request requires preflight, which is disallowed to follow cross-origin redirect

Tags: javascript, ajax, express, cors, fetch-api

I'm using Express for webserver, and using isomorphic-fetch module from client to using XHR.

I have three servers for my web application:

- Port 3000 -> Admin Website
- Port 3001 -> Public Website
- Port 3002 -> API Server

API Server has resources named "skills" which has some data, and get it like this:

```
GET http://mydomain:3002/skills
```

it returns JSON data.

But when I request to 3002 from 3000/3001, it fails with this message:

> Fetch API cannot load http://example.me:3002/skills. Redirect from 'http://example.me:3002/skills' to 'http://example.me:3002/skills/' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request requires preflight, which is disallowed to follow cross-origin redirect.

I don't get it why there is 'redirection' or something. This is my server side code, I granted all CORS related headers:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

...

// CORS
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    var allowedOrigins = ['http://example.me', 'http://example.me:3000', 'http://example.me:3001', 'http://example.me:3002'];
    var origin = req.headers.origin;

    if(allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) > -1){
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
    }

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,Content-Type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD');

    if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
        return res.status(200).end();
    }

    next();
});

app.use(require('./routes'));

...

app.listen(3002, () => console.log(".API Server listening on port 3002..."));
```

And this is client side code that using Fetch API:

```
fetch('http://example.com:3002/skills', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    credentials: 'include',
    cache: 'no-store',
    mode: 'cors'
})...
```

As you can see there is no redirection code. I spent almost a day to fix this issue, but everything I tried was all failed, every information that I found was useless.

I think splitting services to API Server and Web Server(actually returns HTML) was good idea, and want to go with this approach.

Is there a way to fix this problem? Any advice will very appreciate.

Comment: Why are you setting a Content-Type on a GET request?

Comment: Are you allowing Cors on the 3 servers?

Comment: @Quentin I don't remember actually why, I think I just saw somewhere when I was finding some fetch API informations. I just removed that header. Anyway that doesn't matter, still not work.

Comment: @Hosar Yes, of course. I allowed three of them all. You can check this on the server side code, cors middleware part.

Comment: See the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34949492/cors-request-with-preflight-and-redirect-disallowed-workarounds/39728229#39728229 for details of how to work around this. Also as noted there, this restriction on redirects is no longer in the spec but browsers need to update their implementations to match the spec change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue few years ago, still don't get it why it happened.

However my solution was simple, put every API into /api path.