# Request requires preflight, which is disallowed to follow cross-origin redirect

Tags: php, angularjs, nginx

I've an AngularJs form to send a file. When I send the file, the browser performs these requests:

## OPTIONS http://localhost:3000/uploads

### General

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8000/uploads
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8000
```

### Response Headers

```
view source
Accept:*/*
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type,Accept,Authorization,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Request URL,Request Method,Status Code,Remote Address
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Max-Age:1728000
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/plain charset=UTF-8
Content-Type:application/octet-stream
Date:Wed, 04 Jan 2017 10:59:49 GMT
Server:nginx/1.9.14
```

### Request Headers

```
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:8000
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/stocksellout/detail/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36
```

## GET http://localhost:3000/uploads

### Request Headers

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8000/uploads
Request Method:GET
Status Code:301 Moved Permanently
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8000
```

### Response Headers

```
view source
Accept:*/*
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type,Accept,Authorization,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Request URL,Request Method,Status Code,Remote Address
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:3000
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:185
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Wed, 04 Jan 2017 10:59:49 GMT
Location:http://localhost/uploads/
Server:nginx/1.9.14
```

### Request Headers

```
view source
Accept:*/*; q=0.5; application/json
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Authorization:Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXUyJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Im1hZG8iLCJpYXQiOiIxNDgzNTE5NjE2In0.PDcaO8bbX0_OFOhHHJEmao7ZL2d1piLKymVTC_NQNd37kWjZ2F0BZa7-lrbowApfkkbi-nRzPJAoWinEmxnrstJhvN1J59EvbyBuAXNCFdbP08g_8gUS8xPZML3wZW7HieUBwkmSERXpfo08SAzMiQL44j3vtPDLq9US1NBKJQa206YsPX4lWR_rRGxx34tTj_sKf5DSymrTr4ysNRWBuEHRCrvpbclk43kZTH1AgpZHC20nWdAr20uI5BKNNaoPo93wvyYsHx7ufu4zN7bDWfvbm6s_V6rVq0SGDlfzaBLGs1vyEieHOfwNb3gW_xRSYsjFSonvY0-ydWLn5Rzd-HgWMyTVCsD8T4O8esRJWI9hDfLGkzlp2E6RLNp4qn7DpQxQOp0uEq9xL51SaAQClhwlcu0y-ehvdARYPp745vuHxG-2JJOk6OpMF6Na7FTrWuG5nAtseAA-X7wj7julT8-2NxfZQABNMJ01qvNwaAgBCtncFJgxfAzQB33kbN4hSCJ231sfQXAXU164H3fBITM1NP6b37RGrouF8D5RlgW1ErZbVkNN35a8eCKnXbbz9Sb009wEGltLvo9PHs-BxDP2L3bUzmbAYuqSpXogFmCGXF_FMM5mSidyZ_G-xKzdPoTm5NYLypXasZLG_ewzjxA4XOV5AUTjeM5hS0_xpPY
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:173290
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryQp4O7XmLdhbDlNMv
Cookie:selectedTheme=default; io=Scufsf96pJqb8wa7AAAE
Host:localhost:8000
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/stocksellout/detail/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36
```

## POST http://localhost:8000/uploads

### Request headers

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8000/uploads
Request Method:POST
Status Code:301 Moved Permanently
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8000
```

### Response Headers

```
view source
Accept:*/*
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type,Accept,Authorization,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Request URL,Request Method,Status Code,Remote Address
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:3000
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:185
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Wed, 04 Jan 2017 10:59:49 GMT
Location:http://localhost/uploads/
Server:nginx/1.9.14
```

### Request Headers

```
view source
Accept:*/*; q=0.5; application/json
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Authorization:Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXUyJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Im1hZG8iLCJpYXQiOiIxNDgzNTE5NjE2In0.PDcaO8bbX0_OFOhHHJEmao7ZL2d1piLKymVTC_NQNd37kWjZ2F0BZa7-lrbowApfkkbi-nRzPJAoWinEmxnrstJhvN1J59EvbyBuAXNCFdbP08g_8gUS8xPZML3wZW7HieUBwkmSERXpfo08SAzMiQL44j3vtPDLq9US1NBKJQa206YsPX4lWR_rRGxx34tTj_sKf5DSymrTr4ysNRWBuEHRCrvpbclk43kZTH1AgpZHC20nWdAr20uI5BKNNaoPo93wvyYsHx7ufu4zN7bDWfvbm6s_V6rVq0SGDlfzaBLGs1vyEieHOfwNb3gW_xRSYsjFSonvY0-ydWLn5Rzd-HgWMyTVCsD8T4O8esRJWI9hDfLGkzlp2E6RLNp4qn7DpQxQOp0uEq9xL51SaAQClhwlcu0y-ehvdARYPp745vuHxG-2JJOk6OpMF6Na7FTrWuG5nAtseAA-X7wj7julT8-2NxfZQABNMJ01qvNwaAgBCtncFJgxfAzQB33kbN4hSCJ231sfQXAXU164H3fBITM1NP6b37RGrouF8D5RlgW1ErZbVkNN35a8eCKnXbbz9Sb009wEGltLvo9PHs-BxDP2L3bUzmbAYuqSpXogFmCGXF_FMM5mSidyZ_G-xKzdPoTm5NYLypXasZLG_ewzjxA4XOV5AUTjeM5hS0_xpPY
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:173290
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryQp4O7XmLdhbDlNMv
Cookie:selectedTheme=default; io=Scufsf96pJqb8wa7AAAE
Host:localhost:8000
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/stocksellout/detail/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryQp4O7XmLdhbDlNMv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="importFiles"; filename="Clio.jpeg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryQp4O7XmLdhbDlNMv--
```

I've also configured my Nginx with:

```
location /uploads {
     if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Accept' '*/*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type,Accept,Authorization,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Request URL,Request Method,Status Code,Remote Address';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 200;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Accept' '*/*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type,Accept,Authorization,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Request URL,Request Method,Status Code,Remote Address';
     }
     if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Accept' '*/*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type,Accept,Authorization,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Request URL,Request Method,Status Code,Remote Address';
     }
}
```

I always get same error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/uploads. Redirect
>   from 'http://localhost:8000/uploads' to 'http://localhost/uploads/'
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: Request requires preflight, which is
>   disallowed to follow cross-origin redirect.

I've NelmioCorsBundle:

```
270 nelmio_cors:
  1     defaults:
  2         allow_credentials: false
  3         allow_origin: []
  4         allow_headers: []
  5         allow_methods: []
  6         expose_headers: []
  7         max_age: 0
  8         hosts: []
  9         origin_regex: false
 10     paths:
 11         '^/':
 12             allow_origin: ['*']
 13             allow_headers: ['*']
 14             allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'GET', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS', 'LINK', 'UNLINK']
 15             max_age: 3600
```

Can someone explain me what's wrong? Why I cannot upload files? What's wrong in my configuration?

Comment: See the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34949492/cors-request-with-preflight-and-redirect-disallowed-workarounds/39728229#39728229 for details of how to work around this. Also as noted there, this restriction on redirects is no longer in the spec but browsers need to update their implementations to match the spec change.