# Google OAuth2: Redirect has been blocked by CORS policy: Request requires preflight, which is disallowed to follow cross-origin redirect

Tags: node.js, angular, redirect, cors, oauth-2.0

Trying to implement Google OAuth2 and using https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client#authorizing-and-authenticating as reference.  When redirecting user to consent page like this

```
var url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: some_scope
    });
 res.redirect(url);
```

I get this error in browser console (links edited):

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:8080/myPageName. Redirect from localhost:8080/myPageName to accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=... has been blocked by CORS policy: Request requires preflight, which is disallowed to follow cross-origin redirect.

The strange thing is that I am getting this error only when executing the flow from GUI (user presses the button; angular2 front-end). When I put localhost:8080/myPageName directly into the browser address bar everything works fine (get consent form and then tokens).

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I'm getting that same issue :( Doing it from a java spring app, but getting same behavior. Hitting the path directly works (prompts for account etc).

Comment: See the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34949492/cors-request-with-preflight-and-redirect-disallowed-workarounds/39728229#39728229 for details of how to work around this. Also as noted there, this restriction on redirects is no longer in the spec but browsers need to update their implementations to match the spec change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue (with a react frontend, but it's the same).
This is probably because from the server you use redirect, which triggers CORS (even if from your server you allow it).

you have to return the redirect URL to your front-end in some other way, capture it from the front-end app and then call the URL you need to invoke.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is create a hidden link with the required query parameters and click the link using JavaScript, if google supports HTTP POST submission then a hidden form can be created and submitted directly again using JavaScript magic to bypass the CORS restriction which I guess is either already removed or will be removed in near future.