# How do I get HTML back from a cURL in PHP vs. an actual link?

Tags: php, jquery, curl, oauth-2.0

I am new to cURL.

When I make the following GET in jquery/ajax, I receive HTML in the response that creates a popup login window (oauth2).

When I use the following code in a backend php script to hit the same endpoint, I get back a clickable link...which, when clicked takes you to a login page.

What am I missing?

**The PHP**

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://oauthserverxxx.com//login/oauth2/auth?client_id=11111&response_type=code&scope=/auth/userinfo&redirect_uri=http://localhost/oauth_complete.php");

$result = curl_exec($curl);
```

**Response from cURL**

> You are being redirected.bool(true)
>   1

**The AJAX/jquery**

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://client.instructure.com//login/oauth2/auth?client_id=6666&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://oauth_complete.php",
        // dataType: 'html',
        processData: true,
        success: function(canvasAuthHTML) {

          $('#flexModalHeader').html('Login...');
          $('#flexModalMsg').html(canvasAuthHTML);
          $('#flexModal').modal('show');
          console.log('Called Canvas - response: ' + canvasTok);
        },
        error: function (data) {
               console.log('Fail - could not get LTI auth token...');
               chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ msg: "oauthLTI", token: "failed"});
        }
      });
```

**Response**
This will pop the login form *inside* the modal - the response from the server is detailed HTML.

Comment: Did you try adding the curl_setopt of `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`?

Comment: Hadn't tried that...but when I do I get "bool(false)" as a response...not HTML like I get from the AJAX...

Comment: Ok, sounds like that may be problematic then (it has for me in the past). But with it being an oauth url and redirect, I fear you may have issues with it trying to setup cookies and sessions and authenticating in its process. Which you will have trouble/difficulties with curl on.

Comment: I get the gist of what you're saying. I only went to PHP because I was running into CORS issues with jquery.

Comment: Yup, which is another security measure that can get in the way in situations ;)

Comment: Just when you think things are starting to feel rational...

This seems like a crazy box canyon...but the "simple solution" on this answer, below the accepted answer, just helped me a lot...back to jquery:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703169/google-oauth2-redirect-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-request-requires-prefli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could be several things,

first off, the jQuery request probably uses an pre-existing cookie session, your curl request doesn't have any cookies.

second, the jQuery request follows ["Location" http-header-redirects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location), your curl code doesn't, but if that is the problem, you can instruct curl to do the same by setting CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to 1.

third, the jQuery request has an user-agent string, your curl request does not (libcurl has no default user-agent. the curl cli program does, but libcurl, which you use through php's curl_ functions, doesn't.), some websites block requests with no user-agent. if that's the problem, you can simply copy jQuery's user-agent string and tell curl to use it with CURLOPT_USERAGENT

fourth, by default, most browsers use compression where possible, but your curl request doesn't support compression. it's unlikely, but possible, that the server handles curl's request differently because it doesn't support compressed transfers, if that's the problem, you can enable compression in your curl request by setting CURLOPT_ENCODING to emptystring (that will enable all compressions that libcurl was compiled with, which is usually gzip and deflate) - actually, i recommend doing this regardless, because you're fetching HTML, which compresses really well, so unless your cpu is really slow, it will also make the code execute faster. that's the same reason browsers do it by default.

.- the most reliable way to find the culprit, is to record both requests, compare them side by side, and take away every single difference in the 2 requests, 1 by 1, until the requests are identical. sooner or later, you'll find the difference that made the server respond differently (and my best guess here is a location redirect), for that, i recommend the program [FiddlerProxy](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

Comment: @11teenth you're welcome, did you figure out what made the server respond differently to curl's request?

Comment: No - I went into avoidance mode vs. fix mode:) I added a hidden link to the page and have my javascript click it (avoiding CORS problems) which is getting me to the necessary destination so far. I did install Postman but have zero expertise tracking these differences down...but at least have a glimmering of why there is a difference.