# Google Oauth implementation using MEAN stack

Tags: angularjs, node.js, google-oauth

I am having doubts on the architecture for a simple app i am desiging.

My rest based api server is in Node which is at http://localhost:3000
My client is written in Angular 2 at http://localhost:4200

While developing my rest node api server I was successful in implementing passport google authentication which i tested using http://localhost:3000/auth/google and
I get redirected to the google login page and then further after logging in i get redirected to my /profile served by my rest node api

Now i am trying to do the same but starting point is my angular client which calls the node api server to call google auth. so my initial request starts from 
http://localhost:4200 which does a http.get to 
http://localhost:3000/auth/google. hoping that the google auth page shows up for me to authenticate but i get the below error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_ur…=1000090953925-p7jof0qa284ihknb5sor3i4iatnqarvo.apps.googleusercontent.com.
>   Redirect from
>   'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_ur…=1000090953925-p7jof0qa284ihknb5sor3i4iatnqarvo.apps.googleusercontent.com'
>   to
>   'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?passive=1209600&continue=https://a…sercontent.com%26from_login%3D1%26as%3D60339aeceb428c&oauth=1&sarp=1&scc=1'
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is
>   therefore not allowed access.

I have included the url's with both the ports in google auth page under Authorised JavaScript origins
http://localhost:3000
http://localhost:4200
 and in the Authorised redirect URIs
i have included
http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback

Below code in the node api server

app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope : ['profile', 'email'] }));
      app.get('/auth/google/callback',
                passport.authenticate('google', {
                        successRedirect : '/profile',
                        failureRedirect : '/users'
                }),
              );

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Two things: because the backend and frontend are on different ports you'll need to have your backend include the [CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin) on your responses.  Something like this if you're using express:

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

Also, just make sure that the address in the browser is constantly ***http***://localhost  and not ***file***://localhost

Comment: hi Roy, i didn't want the api server to be able to be called by any other application except the front end so i have the below in api server allowing only my client app running on port4200     res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

Comment: Hey Vinay, you should add the protocol too if you're specifying a domain.  So add http:// in front of localhost:4200.

Comment: not working then i added the * but still issue with redirect    XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/auth/google. Redirect from 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google' to 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_ur…=1000090953925-p7jof0qa284ihknb5sor3i4iatnqarvo.apps.googleusercontent.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request requires preflight, which is disallowed to follow cross-origin redirect.

Comment: Sorry missed that before.  Add OPTIONS to your Allow Methods: res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');

Comment: tried that too. would it be possible to communicate via email. if yes, my email is vinaykaran@gmail.com. i can share the angular and node code i have

Comment: Here's a question that handles the redirect error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34949492/cors-request-with-preflight-and-redirect-disallowed-workarounds
Setting up OAUTH with a REST backend is a little tricky and you're going to run into a lot more of these sort of requirements.

Comment: i used a npm module angular2-social-login  for angular 2 and got it working without going through the rest api for the social logins.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is 
send `$window.location.href="URL"`

Hope it helps