# django-cors-headers not working when i18n is on

Tags: django, channel, django-cors-headers, daphne

I have a working environment with:

- `django==1.10`
- `django-rest-framework==3.5.3`
- `djangorestframework-jsonapi==2.1.1`
- `channels` (latest)
- `daphne` (latest) instead of `gunicorn`.

I'm using `nginx` as a proxy server above `daphne`, inside a docker environment.

I'm building a separate `angular 2` SPA that connects to the above backend and
I'm using `django-cors-headers==2.0.2` to allow connections from that web app.

**It works with: USE_I18N = False**

It works fine when I set Django's `USE_I18N = False`. When trying to authenticate against the backend, I send a POST request equivalent to:

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json" -X POST -d '{"data": {"type": "obtainJSONWebTokens", "attributes": {"email":"admin@email.com", "password":"password"}}}' http://localhost/api/auth/login/ --verbose`

Output from curl:

```
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 80 (#0)
> POST /api/auth/login/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.49.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json
> Content-Length: 107
>
* upload completely sent off: 107 out of 107 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.11.9
< Date: Mon, 20 Mar 2017 13:00:47 GMT
< Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Allow: POST, OPTIONS
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Content-Language: en
< Vary: Accept, Accept-Language, Cookie
<
{"data":{"token":"<token>"}}
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

I receive the JWT Token that I am supposed to receive. All works fine.

**It fails with: USE_I18N = True**

However, the same connection fails when `USE_I18N = True`.

Output from curl:

```
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 80 (#0)
> POST /api/auth/login/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.49.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json
> Content-Length: 107

* upload completely sent off: 107 out of 107 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Server: nginx/1.11.9
< Date: Mon, 20 Mar 2017 12:53:49 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: /en/api/auth/login/
< Vary: Cookie
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

The returned error on the client side is:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/api/auth/login/. Redirect from 'http://localhost/api/auth/login/' to 'http://localhost/en/api/auth/login/' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request requires preflight, which is disallowed to follow cross-origin redirect.`

Relevant settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS += (
    'corsheaders',
)

if DEBUG is True:
    CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.admindocs.middleware.XViewMiddleware',
)
```

It would seem it's not the client request that fails but the redirection from 'http://localhost/api/auth/login/' to 'http://localhost/en/api/auth/login/', where Django adds the 'en' to the URL.

Can someone shed any light into this?

I've searched for `django-cors-headers` related issues but none is specific to this apparent incompatibility with I18N. The library works fine without I18N, just not with it on.

**EDIT 2017-03-21**

Given the limitations stated in the accepted answer, I opted by simply avoiding Django's language URL redirections. While using `USE_I18N = True`, I completely avoided `i18n_patterns` in the root URLconf.

In fact, Django Rest Framework states this is a best practice for API clients:

> If you want to allow per-request language preferences you'll need to include `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` in your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting.
>
> You can find more information on how the language preference is determined in the Django documentation. For reference, the method is:
>
> - First, it looks for the language prefix in the requested URL.
> - Failing that, it looks for the `LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY` key in the current user’s session.
> - Failing that, it looks for a cookie.
> - Failing that, it looks at the `Accept-Language` HTTP header.
> - Failing that, it uses the global `LANGUAGE_CODE` setting.
>
> For API clients the most appropriate of these will typically be to use the `Accept-Language` header; Sessions and cookies will not be available unless using session authentication, and generally better practice to prefer an `Accept-Language` header for API clients rather than using language URL prefixes.

So, I kept the above settings the same but changed the following in the root `URLconf`:

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(_(r'^api/$'), SwaggerSchemaView.as_view(), name='api'),
    url(_(r'^api/account/'), include(account_patterns, namespace='account')),
    url(_(r'^api/auth/'), include(auth_patterns, namespace='auth')),
    url(_(r'^api/'), include('apps.party.api.urls', namespace='parties')),
    url(_(r'^api/'), include('apps.i18n.api.urls', namespace='i18n')),
    url(_(r'^api-auth/'), include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(_(r'^admin/'), include(admin_patterns)),
    url(_(r'^docs/'), include('apps.docs.urls'))
)
```

to

```
urlpatterns += ([
    url(_(r'^api/$'), SwaggerSchemaView.as_view(), name='api'),
    url(_(r'^api/account/'), include(account_patterns, namespace='account')),
    url(_(r'^api/auth/'), include(auth_patterns, namespace='auth')),
    url(_(r'^api/'), include('apps.party.api.urls', namespace='parties')),
    url(_(r'^api/'), include('apps.i18n.api.urls', namespace='i18n')),
    url(_(r'^api-auth/'), include('rest_framework.urls',     namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(_(r'^admin/'), include(admin_patterns)),
    url(_(r'^docs/'), include('apps.docs.urls'))]
)
```

So, now, doing:

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json" -H "Accept-Language: pt" -X POST -d '{"data": {"type": "obtainJSONWebTokens", "attributes": {"email":"admin@email.com", "password":"password"}}}' http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login/ --verbose`

returns the expected response in the requested language (please notice the inclusion of `"Accept-Language: pt"` in the request above):

```
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8000 (#0)
> POST /api/auth/login/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.49.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json
> Accept-Language: pt
> Content-Length: 107
>
* upload completely sent off: 107 out of 107 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Allow: POST, OPTIONS
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Vary: Accept, Accept-Language, Cookie
< Content-Language: pt
< Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json
<
{"data":    {"token":"<token>"}}
*     Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In essence, you're running into a bug in an older version of the CORS standard.

The original standard basically made it impossible to do local redirects when using prelight requests. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34949492/cors-request-with-preflight-and-redirect-disallowed-workarounds) on the subject, along with [this bug report](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/204) on the Fetch standard.

In your case this happens with `USE_I18N = True` because that setting is what triggers the redirects.

Hopefully the fix will soon be implemented by the browsers. (According to the [latest report](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/204#issuecomment-286088120) on the Fetch bug it already works in Edge.) In the meantime, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39728229/2395796) suggests some workarounds.

Comment: I accepted this answer. Given the limitations stated in the explanations and links provided, I opted by simply avoiding Django's language redirections. While using `USE_I18N = True`, I completely avoided `i18n_patterns`. I've edited the question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem since I did not use the `i18n_patterns` for all my URLs and one of the URLs that was not inside `i18n_patterns` returned a 404 response.
I solved it by overwriting the Middleware LocaleMiddleware that imports Django by default.

```
class CustomLocaleMiddleware(LocaleMiddleware): 
  def current_urlpattern_is_locale(self, path):
      try:
          resolver = get_resolver(None).resolve(path)
      except Resolver404:
        return self.is_language_prefix_patterns_used()
      return isinstance(resolver, LocaleRegexURLResolver)

  def process_response(self, request, response):
    language = translation.get_language()
    language_from_path = translation.get_language_from_path(request.path_info)
    if (response.status_code == 404 and not language_from_path
            and self.current_urlpattern_is_locale(request.path)):
        urlconf = getattr(request, 'urlconf', None)
        language_path = '/%s%s' % (language, request.path_info)
        path_valid = is_valid_path(language_path, urlconf)
        if (not path_valid and settings.APPEND_SLASH
                and not language_path.endswith('/')):
            path_valid = is_valid_path("%s/" % language_path, urlconf)

        if path_valid:
            script_prefix = get_script_prefix()
            language_url = "%s://%s%s" % (
                request.scheme,
                request.get_host(),
                # insert language after the script prefix and before the
                # rest of the URL
                request.get_full_path().replace(
                    script_prefix,
                    '%s%s/' % (script_prefix, language),
                    1
                )
            )
            return self.response_redirect_class(language_url)

    if not (self.is_language_prefix_patterns_used()
            and language_from_path):
        patch_vary_headers(response, ('Accept-Language',))
    if 'Content-Language' not in response:
        response['Content-Language'] = language
    return response
```