# Can JavaScript script catch redirection info of bad CORS fetch/XHR request?

Tags: javascript, redirect

I am doing a side-project that shows some useful information for people in my organization. The information is not any top-secret thing, however, it is still not proper to expose them directly to people outside my organization. I designed them to be expressed in JSON format and it could be difficult to read without front-end rendering.

My server is out there in the public network, not the internal network. I know some existing URLs that have redirection configured at router level. If people are visiting from the public network, the router will redirect their requests to `public.foo.com` and if the requests are coming from private network, the router will redirect them to `internal.foo.com`.

I tried making such probe requests by using `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch` in hope to see which URL the request is re-directed to, so that I can check the visitor's identity.

```
Failed to load [probe_url]: Redirect from [probe_url]
to [WHAT_I_WANT] has been blocked by CORS policy: No
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
requested resource. Origin [my_front_end_url] is
therefore not allowed access.
```

However, it seems the redirection info are only exposed to the browser, but not down to the document scope. Neither `xhr.onerror = console.log(this)` nor `fetch('//,,,/').catch(ermsg => console.log(ermsg))` can produce the output I want since no CORS requests have been successfully made.

Unfortunately, CORS requests are not allowed at the browser level, so no response is formed and the error message is not captured by my call functions.

I wanted this side-project to be a pure static front-end project to keep things simple. Is it possible to do so, or is there any alternatives, without any backend configuration?

Comment: this might be better done with an underlying redirect with nginx or apache

Comment: @SterlingArcher Thanks for your comment! I can configure the server but I do want to keep the project in front-end only scale...

Comment: Does the server response with a `301`, `302`, `303`, `307` or `308` header?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, it does. But with the browser's safety policy, no response is returned.

Comment: How do you expect to get information about the request where the server does not response with CORS headers?

Comment: @guest271314 Thank you for your follow-up! From the error message, I think the browser get the redirection header from the server, but I can't get the redirection info using my script. I am just looking for a solid answer, be it "you can do it" or "you can never do it".

Comment: If the server does not respond with CORS headers it is not generally possible to get the response headers of a cross-origin request using native `fetch()` alone

Comment: @guest271314 Thanks a lot! And I think I have found a nice explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34949492/cors-request-with-preflight-and-redirect-disallowed-workarounds).